# What are the most common album layouts besides the classical one?

Tags: print-design, book

When one try to make/publish a photo album the most common layout is the one with one photo per page.

What other layouts are proven to be successful, especially considering that we intent to print on some pages small photo reports of 3-6 photos linked between them.

PS: "photo report" = several photos linked together which try to tell a short story

Comment: If you could add some information to this question it would be easier to answer. Are you talking about something like a graphic novel? Will the number of images vary on each page?

Comment: Somewhat. It will be a thematic album - for example the life in an African community. And on some pages will be short photo-stories like "the meal", "chase", "harvesting" etc.

Comment: This isn't an answerable question, really. It's heavily dependent on context.

Comment: The first two steps in almost any difficult design problem: identify what the tradeoff is (almost all design problems are rooted in competing demands), then work out what the acceptable limit for compromise is on each side of the tradeoff. It sounds like yours is: the desire to showcase each photo at full size, without distraction, versus the desire to link photos in a sequence where they can be seen side by side. If the problem is, photos in a photo report must be full size, but, must be viewable side by side, have you considered pages that fold out?

Comment: I agree with @user568458. One important question which must be answered is "budget": how much space, how much does it cost, what MUST be in it. These will quickly eliminate certain options.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this question for a while, but never found a good example of what a new layout for an album could look like.

The presentation will depend on your contents, and each page you need will require a complete design. So it's difficult to recommend a layout that flexible enough.

Two things that came to my mind though, are digital collages and scrapbooks. These might serve as inspiration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]